# Any ideas on how GeneralMiniMaxApproximation is implemented?

Tags: numerics, implementation-details, approximation, reference-request

`GeneralMiniMaxApproximation` is used to construct minimax approximations of parametrically defined functions. I am curious about how `GeneralMiniMaxApproximation` is implemented (just a general overview). Any ideas? Or is this a *Mathematica* trade secret?!

The document states that `MiniMaxApproximation` uses Remez's second algorithm, but does this algorithm extend to parametrically defined functions? I can't seem to locate any references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The references mentioned in the other answer do not really pertain too much to the problem of minimax approximation; they are more concerned with the other functions in `` FunctionApproximations` ``  that deal with numerical differential equation solving; that is, the content that was once in the old `` NumericalMath` `` packages `` Butcher` ``  and `` OrderStar` `` .

Indeed, a look at the contents of the old `` NumericalMath`Approximations` ``  package, where `GeneralMiniMaxApproximation[]` once was, yields the following refs:

> Carl-Erik Fröberg, *Numerical Mathematics: Theory and Computer Applications*, Benjamin/Cummings, 1985, pp. 250-266
>
> A. Ralston & P. Rabinowitz, *A First Course in Numerical Analysis* (2nd. ed.), McGraw-Hill, New York, 1978

I do not possess a copy of the first ref, but I have a copy of the second one; the discussion of Remez's second algorithm is [here](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=czHV-1bEFl0C&pg=PA315). The papers in that book's bibliography are also to be pursued.

Answer (score 6):

You can check [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/FunctionApproximations/tutorial/FunctionApproximationsReferences.html) for Function Approximations Package References

References

- Hairer, E. and G. Wanner. Solving Ordinary Differential Equations II: Stiff and Differential-Algebraic Problems. Springer, 1991.
- Iserles, A. and S. P. Nørsett. Order Stars. Chapman and Hall, 1991.
- Lambert, J. D. Numerical Methods for Ordinary Differential Systems:
  The Initial Value Problem. John Wiley and Sons, 1991.
- Sofroniou, M. "Order Stars and Linear Stability Theory." Journal
  of Symbolic Computation 21, no. 1 (1996): 101-131.

and if you check the **Mathematica\8.0\AddOns\Packages\FunctionApproximations\Approximations.m** you can browse the code. The fourth method for approximation is what you need. It's been stated that `GeneralMiniMaxApproximation` is the same as `MiniMaxApproximation`, except that the function may be specified parametrically, and the error being minimized need not be the relative error.